# HTML form data not saved in database - django

Tags: django, forms, django-templates, django-admin, django-database

I can get data from html but it wont save to database  what should i do ?
it works correctly the only problem is that it wont be save

views.py

```
def comment(request , newsId):
cm = get_object_or_404(models.News , id= newsId)
print("news = " + newsId)

if request.method == 'POST' :
    cm.comments_set.text = request.POST.get('comment_text')
    cm.comments_set.name = request.POST.get('comment_name')
    cm.save()


return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('details', args=(cm.id,)))
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.test),
   path('details/<newsId>', views.details, name="details"),
   path('comment/<newsId>' , views.comment ,name="comment")]
```

models.py

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    description = models.TextField()
    like = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    img = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comments(models.Model):
    news = models.ForeignKey(News, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

html form

```
<form action="{% url 'comment' newsKey.id %}" method="POST">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <textarea name="comment_text" id="comment_text_id"  cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Write your here comment here"></textarea>
     <input type="text" name="coment_name" id="comment_name_id"  placeholder="Type full name"/>
     <button type="submit" value="comment_submit"> SUBMMIT </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing here is saving the original `News` object (*not* a `Comment`) after settings some random properties on the `comments_set`.

Basically you're shooting blanks :)

```py
# fix this part. 
news_article = get_object_or_404(models.News, id=newsId)

comment = models.Comment(
    name=request.POST.get('comment_name' , ''), 
    text=request.POST.get('comment_text',''),
    news=news_article 
)

comment.save()
```

The `comment_set` is used to select all the related comments to the given `News` article.

See this [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#related-objects).

The above can also be shortened by using the `create` method like so:

```py
models.Comment.objects.create(
    name=request.POST['comment_name'], 
    text=request.POST['comment_text'],
    news=news_article 
)
```

This method also saves to the database.